# Git Hub + IntelliJ IDEA: запушить в репозиторий

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea, github

Никогда не юзал гит, решил что время попробовать.
Пишу проект под android.
Создал с помощью идеи репозиторий на гитхабе, добавил туда все файлы и запушил. Но папка src и все что в ней не запушилась. Решил добавить её. Добавил. Попробовал запушить - неудача опять. Как решить?

Comment: попробуйте писать более развернутые вопросы. Если у Вас что то не получилось, опишите детально, что именно, какая именно ошибка и тому подобное.

Comment: На всякий уточню: точно запушили, а не закомиттили?

Comment: проблему решил.

Comment: @papushaev - напишите решение